# I am trying to host a 360 video, in VR (cardboard), full screen

Tags: video, web, virtual-reality, webvr

I have a cardboard VR headset, and my aim is that someone with one can go to my page and stick their cardboard VR on and watch my 360 video.

I want the VR view to be default.

I have been to https://developers.google.com/cardboard/vrview and spent hours trying to get the examples to work. I've tried on multiple browsers with no luck. I think the examples are broken, so I've no way to make them work.

If anything, they just create a black iFrame.

Some examples produce an unusable 'play' bar with only a play button.

Is anyone aware of the instructions/correct code to be able to host this project with all the VR code also hosted (to avoid iOS issues) in the same place?

I do have hosting and a equirectangular 360 video.

Thank you so, so much. I have been banging my head against a wall for hours and hours!!

— Jonothan.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

> https://mercury-noise.glitch.me/

It uses Aframe as markup to load the video files and have all the WebVR controls integrated into your application. As you asked, once a user visits the site on a cardboard it will automatically start playing the video as soon as they enter VR mode.

See the index file to see other controllers as well to start playing the video. For this example I have disabled others and enabled autoplay depending on whether the user is inside VR mode or not.

You should be able to see the code and how to load the video in glitch source code viewer.

It is defined here

```
source type="video/mp4"
src="https://ucarecdn.com/fadab25d-0b3a-45f7-8ef5-85318e92a261/"
```